# Setting up a Ground node using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I've been designing a game where I want the game to stop as soon as the ball makes contact with the ground. My function below is intended to set up the ground.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

     var ground = SKNode() 

     let groundCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
     let ballCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

     //Generic Anchor coordinate points
     let anchorX: CGFloat = 0.5
     let anchorY: CGFloat = 0.5
     /*Sets the background and ball to be in the correct dimensions*/

     override init(size: CGSize) {
         super.init(size: size)

         //Create the Phyiscs of the game
         setUpPhysics()  

         setUpGround()   

         setUpBall()
    }

    func setUpPhysics() -> Void {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -5.0 )
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

     func setUpGround() -> Void {
        self.ground.position = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height)
        self.ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)) //Experiment with this
        self.ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

        self.ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory    //Assigns the bit mask category for ground
        self.ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory  //Assigns the contacts that we care about for the ground

        /*Added in*/
        self.ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

        self.ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.ground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        /**/

        self.addChild(self.ground)
    }

    func setUpBall() -> Void {

        ball.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(anchorX, anchorY)

        self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)

        self.ball.name = "ball"
        self.ball.userInteractionEnabled = false

        ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        self.ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory    //Assigns the bit mask category for ball
        self.ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | ceilingCategory //Assigns the collisions that the ball can have
        self.ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory   //Assigns the contacts that we care about for the ball

        addChild(self.ball)  //Add ball to the display list
    }
```

The problem I am noticing is that when I run the iOS Simulator, the Ground node is not being detected. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ballCategory should be assigned to self.ground.contactBitMask not the ball.

Answer (score 3):

Is your ground node not showing up at all? I believe your ground should be an SKSpriteNode. Add that SKSpriteNode as a child of the SKNode object you created.
The SKNode is an empty node and the SKSpriteNode has an actual visual representation. And instead of doing it in a separate function, it would be much simpler if you did it in the DidMoveToView itself.

```
var objects = SKNode()
addChild(objects)
let ground = SKNode()
ground.position = .......
let colorsprite1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourimageoftheground")
ground.addChild(colorsprite1)
ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

Yes you were right to set ground's physics definition as not dynamic. I don't know why people are telling you otherwise. You don't want it to move upon contact with your ball thingies or whatever it is you have moving around in your scene.

Add all other physics definitions you need. Consider using a ContactTestBitMask as you want SpriteKit to let you know when a collision with the ground occurs, instead of SpriteKit handling it by itself. Details about that mask is easily available in StackOverFlow with examples.

```
objects.addChild(ground)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `dynamic` property to `true` in order for contact detection to work.

At the same time, you can set the following properties.

```
ground.affectedByGravity = false
ground.allowsRotation = false
```

Comment: Hm, thank you but that still does not resolve my issue. The node is not detected for some reason still. I edited my original question to show the updated code.

Comment: Please post the code where you declare the bitmask values

Comment: I updated my OP with the code where I set the bit mask values for the ball. The initial categorization is right at the top.

Comment: Not being able to understand your problem... What exactly do you mean by 'the Ground node is not being detected'? Is the contact not working, or is the node being rendered improperly?

Comment: Oh I see... You still are setting `self.ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false` before you assign the bitMask values. Please remove that line altogether.